# How to share methods between multiple wpf apps with a library

Tags: wpf, dll

I have half a dozen separate wpf apps which run simultaneously. However, they have a lot of overlapping code, eg in connecting to a database and sending notifications. I would like to be able to write these methods once and have all the wpf apps be able to use the same definitions. If there are changes to these shared methods I want to be able to update them together.

I have tried setting up a .Net standard class library, but then I can't use "using System.Data.Odbc" which I need for my methods. I've also tried the WPF user control library and the WPF custom control library but when I try and call the methods I get the error "The name XXX does not exist in the current context." I have added a reference to the library but it's not helping.

What is the best way to have shared methods? Am I on the right track with the libraries?

```
// USER CONTROL

namespace WpfControlLibrary1

{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } 
    }

// MY CODE HERE - HAVE TRIED SEVERAL TESTS
    public static class mytest
    {
        public static string Mytest()
        {
            return "Test123";
        }

        public static string Mytest2(this String str)
        {
            return "Test123";
        }
    }
}

// EXAMPLE XAML.CS FOR APP. HAVE TRIED TO CALL MYTEST AND MYTEST2 BUT THEY DON'T EXIST
namespace MY_Logic
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Mytest();

            string testword = "test";
            testword.Mytest2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just use a normal .Net library. Then you add a reference to the library and the using statement.

Comment: @SledgeHammer if I use a .NET Standard class library, when I add my using System.Data.Odbc statement I get the error "The type or namespace Odbc does not exist in the namespace System.Data (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: I said .Net, not .Net Standard. The system.data references should already be there.

Comment: In Visual Studio when I go to add a .net library I can see .NET core, .NET Standard and .NET framework. I've now switched to .NET framework and it's working! Thanks for your help :)